# I want to show category in the post title , how can I do

Tags: posts, categories, title

[image]

How to add Category name to post title ? “PostTitle + CategoryName”?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `wp_get_post_categories` to loop over the posts categories.

[See Wordpress Docs for more info](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<?php the_category();?>` function to retreive the name of the category.

Using a hook provided by your theme you can place the above function next to the post title.

Example -

`function catname()
{
echo the_category();
}

add_action('after_post_title','catname',10);`

This is just an example code.

If not hook then maybe you need to add it to the single post template using a child theme next to the post title i.e `the_title();`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/